# How to create multicolor border in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to achieve `Imageview` like-

[image]

So far I am using:

```
roundedImage.layer.cornerRadius = roundedImage.frame.width/2
        roundedImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        roundedImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        roundedImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
```

But it's giving me

[image] ,

How to accomplish multi-color rounded border ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that comes in mind is creating a rounded background view colored with a gradient and put your `imageView` on top with a 1px white border

Answer (score 1):

```
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: self.roundedImage.frame.size)
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor]

    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.lineWidth = 2
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: roundedImage.bounds).cgPath
    shape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    gradient.mask = shape

    roundedImage.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Comment: this would be a better approach, use of layer instead of a uiview. More at: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/calayers-tutorial-for-ios-introduction-to-calayers-tutorial

Comment: @Varun Naharia  what is `myButton` ? can you explain more ?

Comment: changed answer please check it's your roundedImage

Answer (score 0):

Try creating **extension to CALayer**.

> It will work across app at other places too.

I have set color as red and pink. Please adjust other values as per your need

**Objective C :**

```
@implementation CALayer(Border)

-(void) addGradientBorderColor {
    CAGradientLayer *objgradientLayer =  [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
    objgradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
    objgradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
    objgradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5);
    objgradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)
    [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(192/255.0) blue:(203/255.0) alpha:1].CGColor];

    CAShapeLayer *objShapeLayer =[[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    objShapeLayer.lineWidth = 0.5;
    objShapeLayer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds].CGPath;
    objShapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
    objShapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    objgradientLayer.mask = objShapeLayer;

    [self addSublayer : objgradientLayer];
}

@end
```

**Swift :**

```
extension CALayer {
    func addGradienBorder(colors:[UIColor] = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor,UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 192/255, blue: 203/255, alpha: 1).CGColor],width:CGFloat = 1) {
        let objgradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        objgradientLayer =  CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: self.bounds.size)
        objgradientLayer = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5)
        objgradientLayer = CGPointMake(1.0, 0.5)
        objgradientLayer = colors.map({$0.CGColor})

        let objShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        objShapeLayer.lineWidth = 1
        objShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).CGPath
        objShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        objShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        objgradientLayer.mask = objShapeLayer

        self.addSublayer(objgradientLayer)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps !